# debug.traceTransaction returns empty structLogs

Tags: go-ethereum, transaction-trace

I have installed a private node using geth (1.9.11-stable). I have created a number of accounts, deployed some contract accounts and sent transactions from the accounts to the contract accounts. By checking the balance on the contract accounts I can see these transactions are successful.

I am now trying to trace the transactions however I keep getting the `structLogs` entry as an empty array.

```
{
  failed: false,
  gas: 21272,
  returnValue: "",
  structLogs: []
}
```

I have read on other posts that for traceTransaction to work the geth node must be started in archival mode. I have done this but I still get the same result (empty `structLogs`).

At the moment I start the geth node using the following command;

```
geth --mine --minerthreads=1 --datadir ~/gethDataDir --networkid 15 --gcmode archive --syncmode full
```

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong and why I am getting `structLogs` as an empty array?

**Edit 1:**

It would seem the issue is related with the smart contract used for testing. When I use a smart contract which only accepts ether and does nothing else the `structLogs` come empty.

```
contract HelloWorld {
    function hello() public payable {}
}
```

When I actually put some logic into the smart contract (using exact same approach to deploy and send transaction to the contract account) the `structLogs` are populated.

```
contract HelloWorld {
    function hello(uint i) public payable returns (uint) { 
        return i * 2; 
    }
}
```

Wouldn't the EVM still be executing instructions in the first case even though just an ether transfer is occurring?